# Aligning Web Map Layers from Bing Maps and Google Maps in QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, bing-maps, quickmapservices

Why doesn't Bing and Google imagery "line up" in QGIS.

Basic steps to replicate the problem:

1. Open new QGIS project and set project CRS to EPSG 3857 (Pseudo Mercator).
2. Open Bing and Google Satellite layers using QuickMapServices plugin.
3. Toggle layers over an urban area, and watch the buildings shift.

The Google imagery seems to line up better with vector layers projected on the fly, so I am assuming that there is a problem with the Bing layer, and how I am using it.

Should I use a different CRS with the QuickMapServices Bing satellite layer?

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  I can't seem to find the answer.  Should I be using a different CRS with Bing Maps?  Thank you to anyone who can point me in the right direction here :)